# "Согласно чему-то" или "согласно чего-то"?

Tags: лингвистика

Как правильно говорить: "согласно чему-то" или "согласно чего-то"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно исключительно "согласно чему-то". Раньше "согласно чего-то" считалось канцеляризмом, но в современном русском языке такой оборот недопустим.

Comment: Предыдущий ответ правильный.