# Почему раньше использовали родительный падеж в сочетании "согласно чему"?

Tags: грамматика, предлоги

**Из [ответа](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/828/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE) на форуме**:

```
  Правильно исключительно "согласно чему-то". Раньше 
  "согласно чего-то" считалось канцеляризмом, но в 
  современном русском языке такой оборот недопустим.
```

Так почему же раньше не видели, что это **канцеляризм**, но считали **допустимым** такое написание? Какие можно предположить версии для **возможного обоснования** Р.п.?

Спасибо.

Ответ задан по недавнему вопросу: **["Согласно сезона» или «согласно сезону»?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/480113/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83).**

Answer (score 1):

1. Раньше "согласно чего-то" считалось канцеляризмом. А потом, вероятно, была внесена **поправка в словари?** Может быть, в **1956 году?** Нет, уже в толковом словаре **Д. Н. Ушакова** 1935—1940 гг. написано: **Согласно чему-нибудь** (но не согласно чего-нибудь). А  когда же? Оказывается,  Р.п. **никогда нормативным не был.**
2. **[Из  статьи "Согласно приказу или приказа?"](https://proza.ru/diary/sireng/2020-11-24)**

На протяжении своей истории этот предлог использовался  с **тремя** падежами (родительный, дательный, творительный), но остался верен только одному.

(1) **Творительный падеж. Согласно с чем**

Именно такое управление рекомендуется в Словаре Императорской Академии Наук **1847 г:** «согласно съ сводомъ законовъ». Это был один из самых авторитетных словарей того времени.
*Савельич, **согласно со мнением ямщика,** советовал воротиться.* А. С. Пушкин. Капитанская дочка. Но Большой толковый словарь правильной русской речи Л. И. Скворцова 2009 года признаёт такое управление **архаичным.**

(2) **Родительный падеж. Согласно чего**

Это характерный признак **официально-деловой и канцелярской** речи ещё с XIX в., употреблялся преимущественно в документах, письмах, деловых записках тех времён. В литературном языке Р.п. не закрепился, **в нормативных словарях его не было.** Существовало любопытное разграничение: один и тот же писатель мог в канцелярском деле употреблять родительный падеж, а в литературном языке — дательный.

(3)  **Дательный падеж. Согласно чему**

В литературном языке **XIX — XX вв. преобладает.** Особенно со второй половины XIX столетия, когда конструкция «согласно с чем» начала постепенно уходить.

2. **Автор** статьи говорит: "***Логику в подобном управлении (Р.п.) найти трудно***". А почему же ее находят? Ошибочное употребление Р.п. существует вопреки всем правилам.

У меня **такая версия.** Одно из основных значений Р.п. — **отложительно-достигательное** по отношению к предмету, предлоги ***ОТ, ИЗ, ДО***. Многие пользователи считают "согласно чего" синонимом "исходя из чего" или "относительно чего".

А "согласно чему" указывает на **направление** к предмету, ориентир на предмет, а это не всем кажется очевидным. У нас в школьной программе нет изучения падежей хотя бы в какой-то форме, а тогда откуда возьмется **грамотная речь**?

Так что **противостояние** продолжается, а мы ждем **новых** вопросов по теме))